# Finding a flight plan for a private plane

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, minneapolis

Can I find a flight plan for a private plane that would have landed and taken off on November 2nd 2016 St Paul, MN airport? This is related to a missing person.

Comment: Planes are not always required to file flight plans, so there may be nothing to find.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you're correct and the FAA has a program called Block Aircraft Registration Request (BARR) whereby private aircraft owners or operators are able to have their aircraft data blocked from public display in ASDI, including those not accompanied by a Certified Security Concern. If it was at MSP, there will likely be a flight plan, but those are generally destroyed after 15 days or so. If law enforcement is involved, it might help; if not, it may be very difficult.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: It may be on topic at aviation SE.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas it is.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It would be on topic, but it would probably be closed as "Too Broad".

Answer (score 7):

To request a flight plan, you would have to file a [Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) request](https://www.faa.gov/foia/foia_request/) to the appropriate regional Federal Aviation Office. Since flight plans are filed regionally, the office managing Minnesota would be the FAA Central Service Center. You are able to [initiate the request online](https://www.faa.gov/foia/email_foia/?region=central) for air traffic records.